# How to Shift the Filling Colour Midpoint Plotting a Map in R

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, geo, r-sp

I have the followign question. I am plotting a map. The regions are coloured depending upon the value of an index that can be positive and / or negative.

I am doing the following:

```
colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("darkred","orange","yellow","springgreen","darkgreen"))
spplot(Regions[c(7,79,67,52,37,39),],
       "PRINT_DATA.2", 
       scales = list(draw = T), 
       col.regions = colfunc(100) 
                          )
```

I get the plot:
[image]

I assume that the midpoint should be 0. In this case the regions having index `PRINT_DATA.2 > 0` will be coloured light- and darkgreen and `PRINT_DATA.2 < 0`- orange and red.

In this sample the spplot calculates the midpoint automatically and so the regions having minor positive values of `PRINT_DATA.2` are coloured orange instead of sorts of green.

I do not want to scale the positive or negative values by something like `max(PRINT_DATA.2(PRINT_DATA.2>0)) / max(abs(PRINT_DATA.2(PRINT_DATA.2<0)))` as it will harm the legend of the plot.

I am sure that the aswer is somewhere on the surface but I am really stuck looking for the way out the second day. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: According to documentation, you can manage scales passing arguments specify in xyplot. There you can add limits to the scale. Maybe try: list(draw = T, limits = c(-0.5,0.5)).

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado Thank you for your response! I tried as you had advised me. But I got an empty plot. The midpoint did not shift. Could you probably add details to your comment?

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado I investigated into your advice. Option `limits` in this case limits the part of the map in limits of longitude and latitude.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I check I do not know how to do it. I know how to do that plot with ggplot2 instead. In ggplo2 you can easily modify the scale, and I can help. If you add sample data, I can respond given a ggplot2 way.